# PDF::FromHTML can't call write_file on undefined value

Tags: html, perl, pdf

I'm trying to generate a PDF-file from an HTML-file with `Perl`. My code looks like this:

```
open HTML, ">", "path_to_file.html";
...
...
close HTML;
chmod(0777, "path_to_file.html");

my $pdf = PDF::FromHTML->new(encoding => 'utf-8');
$pdf->load_file("path_to_file.html") or die $!;

$pdf->write_file("path_to_file.pdf") or die $!;
```

However when I start the script, I get the following error:

```
Can't call method "write_file" on an undefined value at /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.12.3/PDF/FromHTML.pm line 210, <> line 2.
```

I verified, that the html-file is where it should be and has the right permissions (777). Loading the HTML-file seems to be no problem, since the script gets to the very last line before dying.

I also tried creating an empty PDF-file in the target-location but that changed nothing.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your're lacking actual [conversion](http://search.cpan.org/~audreyt/PDF-FromHTML-0.31/lib/PDF/FromHTML.pm#SYNOPSIS) which must take place before write

```
$pdf->convert(..);
```

Comment: Thanks! For some reason I thought, that this step was optional.